# Finding max of nullable date between two columns in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in Db2 called `myTable`.

It has several columns:

```
a |  b    | date1        |  date2
---------------------------------------------
1    abc     <null>        2014-09-02
2    aax     2015-12-30    2016-09-02
2    bax     2015-10-20    <null>
2    ayx     2014-12-10    2016-02-12
```

As seen from values above, `date1` and `date2` can have `null` values as well.

How can I get the max of both `date1` and `date2` together ?

i.e. the output of the query should be 2016-09-02 as that is the max date of all the dates present in `date1` and `date2`.

I am using Db2-9.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT MAX(t.newDate)
FROM
(
    SELECT date1 AS newDate
    FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT date2 AS newDate
    FROM myTable
) t
```

Another option:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.date1 > t.date2 THEN t.date1 ELSE t.date2 END
FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM myTable) AS date1,
           (SELECT MAX(date2) FROM myTable) AS date2
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
) t
```

Comment: LOL...this morning I got totally rocked by Gordon Linoff, but I was on a cell phone at the time :-)

Comment: ANSI SQL has `date` as reserved word. What about db2? (Yes, Gordon is outstandning...)

Answer (score 1):

`MAX()` is an interesting beast...

It's available as both a scalar function and an aggregate one.

So all you really need is

```
select max(max(coalesce(date1,'0001-01-01')
              ,coalesce(date2,'0001-01-01') 
              )
          )
from mytable
```

The outer `MAX()` is the aggregate version, the inner is the scalar one.

Answer (score 0):

Reputation is too low to comment, but I would like to expand on the solution provided by Charles. If none, one or both of the dates could be NULL, then I would expect the result to return

1. either the MAX of two NOT NULL values
2. if one of the values is
   NULL, then the remaining NOT NULL value
3. if both values are NULL,
   then the result ought to be NULL

for each row in the response.

The following would fulfill all requirements, returning a row for each result in the response:

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(
        MAX(
            COALESCE(DATE1, '0001-01-01')
            , COALESCE(DATE2, '0001-01-01')
        )
        , '0001-01-01')
FROM MYTABLE
```

Without the NULLIF(), the issue here would be, that NULL values would be returned as '0001-01-01' .

The additional advantage over the UNION solution would also be, that one could use sub-selects instead of the explicit references DATE1 and DATE2, referencing columns in the outer SQL, fetching the max date value of two dates for each row in the SQL result set, e.g.

```
SELECT
    MYTABLE.SEQ,
    NULLIF(
        MAX(
            COALESCE( ( SELECT DATE1 FROM MYDATETABLE1 WHERE MYDATETABLE1.FK = MYTABLE.SEQ ORDER BY DATE1 DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) , '0001-01-01')
            , COALESCE( ( SELECT DATE2 FROM MYDATETABLE2 WHERE MYDATETABLE2.FK = MYTABLE.SEQ ORDER BY DATE2 DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) , '0001-01-01')
        )
    , '0001-01-01') AS MAXDATE
FROM MYTABLE
```

To solve your original case, here a possible solution:

```
DROP TABLE TMPTABLE;

CREATE TABLE TMPTABLE (
    a INT
    ,b VARCHAR(254)
    ,date1 DATE
    ,date2 DATE
    );

INSERT INTO TMPTABLE
VALUES (1,'abc',CAST(NULL as DATE),'2014-09-02')
    ,(2,'aax','2015-12-30','2016-09-02')
    ,(3,'bax','2015-10-20',CAST(NULL as DATE))
    ,(4,'ayx','2014-12-10','2016-02-12')
    ,(5,'null',CAST(NULL as DATE),CAST(NULL as DATE));

SELECT
    a,
    b
    ,date1
    ,date2
    ,NULLIF(
        MAX(
            COALESCE(date1, '0001-01-01'),
            COALESCE(date2, '0001-01-01')
        )
    , '0001-01-01') as MAXDATE
FROM TMPTABLE;
```

| A | B | DATE1 | DATE2 | MAXDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | NULL | 2014-09-02 | 2014-09-02 |
| 2 | aax | 2015-12-30 | 2016-09-02 | 2016-09-02 |
| 3 | bax | 2015-10-20 | NULL | 2015-10-20 |
| 4 | ayx | 2014-12-10 | 2016-02-12 | 2016-02-12 |
| 5 | null | NULL | NULL | NULL |