# Complex sql query requirement in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table as follows:

```
   keyCol     |     date_O_Col      |    date_C_Col   |    statCol
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1            2007-02-09          2012-11-02          C
      1            1990-01-31          <null>              O
      1            <null>              <null>              O
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query which does the following:

1) Compares the date values in both the date columns to find out the max date between both of them. In the example above `2012-11-02` is the max date in both the columns.

2) Since `2012-11-02` is in `date_C_Col`, the resultant row of the query should be:

```
   keyCol     |     date_O_Col      |    date_C_Col   |    statCol
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1             <null>               2012-11-02          C
```

i.e. send the max date in the column in which it belonged originally with the corresponding `statCol` and send the other date column as null.

As other example, the table status as:

```
       keyCol  |     date_O_Col      |    date_C_Col   |    statCol
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      2            2016-02-09               2016-03-09        C
      2            1990-01-31               2012-11-02        C
      2            2016-03-10               <null>            O
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

should result in:

```
       keyCol  |     date_O_Col      |    date_C_Col   |    statCol
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      2            2016-03-10               <null>            O
```

Since `2016-03-10` is the max date and belongs to `date_O_Col` with corresonding `statCol` as O.

I am using db2 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT keyCol, 
       CASE WHEN date_O_Col = x.date_col THEN date_O_Col END,
       CASE WHEN date_C_Col = x.date_col THEN date_C_Col END,
       statCol
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(date_col) AS date_col
   FROM (SELECT CASE 
                   WHEN COALESCE([date_O_Col], '1900-01-01') > 
                        COALESCE([date_C_Col], '1900-01-01') 
                           THEN date_O_Col 
                   ELSE date_C_Col 
                END AS date_col
         FROM mytable) AS t) AS x
WHERE CASE 
         WHEN COALESCE([date_O_Col], '1900-01-01') > 
              COALESCE([date_C_Col], '1900-01-01') 
                 THEN date_O_Col 
         ELSE date_C_Col 
      END = x.date_col
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/356b3e/1)

Comment: Its returning 0 results :(

Comment: @Vicky I've tested it with the second set of sample data and it returns the correct result.

Comment: Note that `[date_O_Col]` is invalid (standard) SQL and won't work with DB2

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `case`:

```
select t.keycol,
       (case when max(date_O_Col) is null and max(date_C_Col) is null then NULL
             when max(date_O_Col) is null then 'C'
             when max(date_C_Col) is null then 'O'
             when max(date_O_Col) > max(date_C_Col) then 'O'
             when max(date_C_Col) > max(date_O_Col) then 'C'
             else '='
        end)
from t
group by keycol;
```

I made up values for boundary cases that your question doesn't cover:  when the values are both `NULL` or both equal.

Comment: Your answer seems to be incomplete. The query should result in 4 columns as mentioned in my examples. But above answer seems to return only 2 columns. Also, could you please expain a bit if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Building from my answer to your other post [finding-max-of-nullable-date-between-two-columns-in-db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286474/finding-max-of-nullable-date-between-two-columns-in-db2)...

You don't describe what results you want if more than one row has the same max date.  Taking the easy assumption, that you'd want all the rows, then the following would work.

```
select *
from mytable
where (select max(max(coalesce(date1,'00001-01-01')
                      ,coalesce(date2,'00001-01-01') 
                     )
                 )
         from mytable
      ) in (date1, date2)
```

Comment: There is an extra zero in the `year` component of the character-string attempting to be a date literal; the following redaction would explicitly type/cast the constant as a *valid* date: `coalesce(date1,date'0001-01-01')`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understood the requirements, but following the lead of the query offered by Charles, the following setup and query perhaps?:

Setup:

```
create table so39290083 
( keyCol dec(1), date_O_Col date, date_C_Col date,  statCol char)
;
insert into  so39290083 values                                    
/*keyCol dec(1), date_O_Col date, date_C_Col date,  statCol char*/
  (   1   ,       '2007-02-09'  ,     '2012-11-02'    , 'C'  )    
, (   1   ,       '1990-01-31'  ,       null          , 'O'  )    
, (   1   ,        NULL         ,       null          , 'O'  )    
, (   2   ,       '2016-02-09'  ,     '2016-03-09'    , 'C'  )    
, (   2   ,       '1990-01-31'  ,     '2012-11-02'    , 'C'  )    
, (   2   ,       '2016-03-10'  ,       null          , 'O'  )    
;
```

Query:

```
select t.keycol                                                  
     ,  case t.statcol when 'O' then date_O_Col end as date_O_Col
     ,  case t.statcol when 'C' then date_C_Col end as date_C_Col
     , t.statcol                                                 
from so39290083 as T                                             
where ( t.keycol                                                 
      , case t.statcol when 'O' then date_O_Col                  
                       when 'C' then date_C_Col end ) in         
      ( select keycol                                            
             , max(max(coalesce( date_O_Col  , date'0001-01-01') 
                      ,coalesce( date_C_Col  , date'0001-01-01') 
                      ))                                         
        from so39290083 s                                        
        group by keycol                                          
      )                                                          
 ; -- likeness of a report from above query:
 KEYCOL  DATE_O_COL  DATE_C_COL  STATCOL
    1    -           2012-11-02     C   
    2    2016-03-10  -              O   
 ********  End of data  ********
```